Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority when using kubectl
when I using kubectl to access the kubernetes, shows error:
➜  .kube kubectl get nodes -v=9
I0818 17:28:47.544500   96918 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/config
I0818 17:28:47.545804   96918 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.23.0 (darwin/arm64) kubernetes/ab69524" 'https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s'
I0818 17:28:50.537091   96918 round_trippers.go:495] HTTP Trace: DNS Lookup for kubernetes.poemhub.top resolved to [{120.27.115.168 }]
I0818 17:28:50.585626   96918 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:120.27.115.168:443 succeed
I0818 17:28:50.666569   96918 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 2990 ms Dial 47 ms TLSHandshake 80 ms Duration 3120 ms
I0818 17:28:50.666604   96918 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I0818 17:28:50.666711   96918 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I0818 17:28:50.666850   96918 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.23.0 (darwin/arm64) kubernetes/ab69524" 'https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s'
I0818 17:28:53.535382   96918 round_trippers.go:495] HTTP Trace: DNS Lookup for kubernetes.poemhub.top resolved to [{120.27.115.168 }]
I0818 17:28:53.573578   96918 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:120.27.115.168:443 succeed
I0818 17:28:53.629604   96918 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 2868 ms Dial 38 ms TLSHandshake 55 ms Duration 2962 ms
I0818 17:28:53.629624   96918 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I0818 17:28:53.629659   96918 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I0818 17:28:53.629671   96918 shortcut.go:89] Error loading discovery information: Get "https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I0818 17:28:53.629766   96918 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.23.0 (darwin/arm64) kubernetes/ab69524" 'https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s'
I0818 17:28:56.548079   96918 round_trippers.go:495] HTTP Trace: DNS Lookup for kubernetes.poemhub.top resolved to [{120.27.115.168 }]
I0818 17:28:56.596268   96918 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:120.27.115.168:443 succeed
I0818 17:28:56.681816   96918 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 2918 ms Dial 48 ms TLSHandshake 85 ms Duration 3052 ms
I0818 17:28:56.681839   96918 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I0818 17:28:56.681877   96918 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I0818 17:28:56.682006   96918 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.23.0 (darwin/arm64) kubernetes/ab69524" 'https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s'
I0818 17:28:59.536461   96918 round_trippers.go:495] HTTP Trace: DNS Lookup for kubernetes.poemhub.top resolved to [{120.27.115.168 }]
I0818 17:28:59.579077   96918 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:120.27.115.168:443 succeed
I0818 17:28:59.654818   96918 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 2854 ms Dial 42 ms TLSHandshake 75 ms Duration 2972 ms
I0818 17:28:59.654859   96918 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I0818 17:28:59.654918   96918 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I0818 17:28:59.655075   96918 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.23.0 (darwin/arm64) kubernetes/ab69524" 'https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s'
I0818 17:29:02.536323   96918 round_trippers.go:495] HTTP Trace: DNS Lookup for kubernetes.poemhub.top resolved to [{120.27.115.168 }]
I0818 17:29:02.575126   96918 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:120.27.115.168:443 succeed
I0818 17:29:02.653178   96918 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 2881 ms Dial 38 ms TLSHandshake 77 ms Duration 2998 ms
I0818 17:29:02.653206   96918 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I0818 17:29:02.653253   96918 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I0818 17:29:02.653808   96918 helpers.go:236] Connection error: Get https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
F0818 17:29:02.654228   96918 helpers.go:117] Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.stacks(0x1)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:1038 +0xac
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).output(0x1073ca9a0, 0x3, 0x0, 0x140007fa9a0, 0x2, {0x106979b18, 0xa}, 0x75, 0x0)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:987 +0x628
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).printDepth(0x1073ca9a0, 0x3, 0x0, {0x0, 0x0}, 0x2, {0x1400049c780, 0x1, 0x1})
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:735 +0x1ac
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.FatalDepth(...)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:1518
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util.fatal({0x1400054c3c0, 0x4e}, 0x1)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util/helpers.go:95 +0xf4
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util.checkErr({0x1063a5e20, 0x1400002e060}, 0x10639c090)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util/helpers.go:190 +0x8dc
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util.CheckErr(...)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util/helpers.go:117
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get.NewCmdGet.func2(0x140001f1b80, {0x1400048b3a0, 0x1, 0x2})
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/get.go:181 +0x120
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x140001f1b80, {0x1400048b380, 0x2, 0x2})
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:860 +0x640
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x140001bfb80)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:974 +0x410
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:902
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/component-base/cli.Run(0x140001bfb80)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/component-base/cli/run.go:105 +0x36c
main.main()
    _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubectl/kubectl.go:31 +0x24

goroutine 18 [chan receive]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).flushDaemon(0x1073ca9a0)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:1181 +0x70
created by k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.init.0
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:420 +0x150

goroutine 37 [select]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil(0x10639bf70, {0x1063a4240, 0x1400002e000}, 0x1, 0x1400018e360)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:167 +0x118
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil(0x10639bf70, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1400018e360)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133 +0x88
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.Until(...)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:90
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.Forever(0x10639bf70, 0x12a05f200)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:81 +0x50
created by k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/component-base/logs.InitLogs
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/component-base/logs/logs.go:179 +0x98

this is the output from broswser:
{
kind: "Status",
apiVersion: "v1",
metadata: { },
status: "Failure",
message: "forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot get path "/"",
reason: "Forbidden",
details: { },
code: 403
}

why the kubectl could not recognize the certificate? what shoud I do to fixed this issue? I have tried to ignore the certificate like this:
➜  .kube kubectl get nodes --insecure-skip-tls-verify -v=9

I0818 17:31:47.623513     765 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/config
I0818 17:31:47.624915     765 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.23.0 (darwin/arm64) kubernetes/ab69524" 'https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/api?timeout=32s'
I0818 17:31:50.537044     765 round_trippers.go:495] HTTP Trace: DNS Lookup for kubernetes.poemhub.top resolved to [{120.27.115.168 }]
I0818 17:31:50.578369     765 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:120.27.115.168:443 succeed
I0818 17:31:50.672795     765 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 2911 ms Dial 40 ms TLSHandshake 51 ms ServerProcessing 42 ms Duration 3047 ms
I0818 17:31:50.672885     765 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I0818 17:31:50.672910     765 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
I0818 17:31:50.672930     765 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid: eadf225e-0210-40b2-9023-9f2f862b1f89
I0818 17:31:50.672950     765 round_trippers.go:580]     Server: openresty/1.25.3.2
I0818 17:31:50.672970     765 round_trippers.go:580]     Date: Sun, 18 Aug 2024 09:31:50 GMT
I0818 17:31:50.672987     765 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Length: 188
I0818 17:31:50.673005     765 round_trippers.go:580]     Connection: keep-alive
I0818 17:31:50.673024     765 round_trippers.go:580]     Audit-Id: ae787370-9349-48b3-9ac0-bd95d1fc3e3b
I0818 17:31:50.673042     765 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Type: application/json
I0818 17:31:50.673059     765 round_trippers.go:580]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I0818 17:31:50.673076     765 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid: 1c6d7eea-ebb7-41af-931f-526131a91b7c
I0818 17:31:50.684542     765 request.go:1181] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/api\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{},"code":403}
I0818 17:31:50.694870     765 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.23.0 (darwin/arm64) kubernetes/ab69524" -H "Accept: application/json, */*" 'https://kubernetes.poemhub.top/apis?timeout=32s'
I0818 17:31:50.742033     765 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: GetConnection 0 ms ServerProcessing 45 ms Duration 47 ms

the local .kube/config was copied from remote kubernetes cluster folder /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf. Am I missing something? I have also tried to add the kubernetes.poemhub.top to the kubeadm-config.yaml then update the certSANs and recreate the server side certificate, upload the new certSANs config to system, recreate the api server pod to make it work. This is the newest config:
[root@iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ ~]# kubectl -n kube-system get configmap kubeadm-config -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ClusterConfiguration: |
    apiServer:
      certSANs:
      - 10.96.0.1
      - 172.31.227.20
      - 120.27.115.168
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 106.14.183.131
      - kubernetes.poemhub.top
      extraArgs:
        authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
      timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
    apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
    certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
    clusterName: kubernetes
    controllerManager: {}
    dns: {}
    etcd:
      local:
        dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
    imageRepository: registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers
    kind: ClusterConfiguration
    kubernetesVersion: v1.29.6
    networking:
      dnsDomain: cluster.local
      podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
      serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
    scheduler: {}

this is the domain server side forward config:
[root@iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ conf.d]# cat kubernetes.poemhub.top-443.conf
server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  kubernetes.poemhub.top;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/poemhub/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/poemhub/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                client_max_body_size 1m;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_read_timeout 3600;
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:6443;
        }

}

I also tried to forward by using 8080:
kubectl proxy --port=8080
[root@iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ conf.d]# curl -k http://127.0.0.1:8080
tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

seems did not work.

Verify that the $HOME/.kube/config file contains a valid certificate, and regenerate a certificate if necessary.
Unset the KUBECONFIG environment variable using  the below command,
Unset KUBECONFIG
Or set it to the default KUBECONFIG location:
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
Another workaround is to overwrite the existing kubeconfig for the "admin" user as below:
mv $HOME/.kube $HOME/.kube.bak mkdir $HOME/.kube sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

Refer to this documentation for more information on this.

this is exactly what I do, is it possible to kubernetes could not recognize the certificate that I an applied from let's encrypt. when I using ip + port, from local machine to the kubernetes works fine.

Let’s encrypt certificates are usually domain based. Ensure that your domain is correctly pointing to your kubernetes service and the certificate is issued for the right domain. And I would suggest looking at DNS-01 challenge so that you can use the certificate containing the wildcard domain name as an option.
